# How to assign rank to students to where they share the highest rank when their scores equal?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have code that ranks students and it works, but not as I intended -- if two or more students score the same `score` it doesn't `rank` them both in the same `rank`. I want the final ranking to be like this - if two or more students `score` the same result, I want them to `rank` in the same place like this:

```
1. miki ==> 97.8
2. lisa ==> 96.1 
2. jack ==> 96.1
4. john ==> 90.7
```

Note that lisa and jack `score` the same (`96.1`), and it gives them the same `rank` (2nd), and therefore, 3rd is skipped.  John is 4th.

**Current code**

```
$student = '10_E';
$first = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rej_students where student_selected = '$student'");

$teacher = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE tech_id = '1002'");
$teachers = mysql_fetch_array($teacher);

$avg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM avgfct_10 order by AVGFCT_10 desc");

$ra = 0; //rank
while ($go = mysql_fetch_array($avg))
{
    if ($go['AVGFCT_10'] != $go['AVGFCT_10'])
    {
        $micky = $ra ++;
    }
    if ($go['AVGFCT_10'] == $go['AVGFCT_10'])
    {
        $micky = 'same';
    }
    echo "id = " . $go['STUDENT_ID'] . "<br> AVARANGE = " . $go['AVGFCT_10'] . "<br>RANK = " . $micky . "<br> Class = " . $teachers['tech_hclass'] . "<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: It is better to include code here, because links might be removed.. Also, read the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) ..

Comment: this is going to get downvoted faster than the bill for healthcare (sorry had to) - read the tour as @Naruto suggests and try again :)

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please dont post pictures of code. Post the code itself as text

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: The crux of the question, I think, is how to give students the same (highest scored) rank when they share the same numerical `result`, while maintaining the consecutive rank for students who don't have shared result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two counters

- Absolute Counter (always 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc).
- Rank Counter -  it counts from 1 but if the scores are same, it does not update.  As soon as scores are different, it updates with the `absolute counter`.

**Sample Code**

```
$counter = 1; // init absolute counter
$rank = 1; // init rank counter

// initial "previous" score:
$prevScore = 0;
while ($go = mysql_fetch_array($avg))
{
    // get "current" score
    $score = $go['AVGFCT_10'];

    if ($prevScore != $score) // if previous & current scores differ
        $rank = $counter;
    // else //same // do nothing

    echo "Rank: {$rank}, Score: {$score}<br>";
    $counter ++; // always increment absolute counter

    //current score becomes previous score for next loop iteration
    $prevScore = $score;
}
```

Output:

```
Rank: 1, Score: 97.8
Rank: 2, Score: 96.1
Rank: 2, Score: 96.1
Rank: 4, Score: 90.7
```